# How to not remove the header while executing awk

Tags: awk

I have a file `file` like this :

```
k_1_1
k_1_3
k_1_6
...
```

I have a file `file2` :

```
0,1,2,3,...
k_1_1,17,16,15,...
k_1_2,17,89,15,...
k_1_3,10,26,45,...
k_1_4,17,16,15,...
k_1_5,10,26,45,...
k_1_6,17,16,15,...

...
```

I want to print lines of `file2` that is matched with `file`The desired output is :

```
0,1,2,3,...
k_1_1,17,16,15,...
k_1_3,10,26,45,...
k_1_6,17,16,15,...
```

I tried

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$1 in a {print $0}' file file2 > result
```

But the header line is gone in result like this :

```
k_1_1,17,16,15,...
k_1_3,10,26,45,...
k_1_6,17,16,15,...
```

How can a maintain it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always print the first line, unconditionally.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
    NR==FNR{a[$1];next}
    FNR==1 || $1 in a' file file2 > result
```

Notice also how `{ print $0 }` is not necessary because it's the default action.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next} FNR==1 && ++count==1{print;next} a[$1]' Input_file  Input_file2
```

OR

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next} FNR==1{print;next} a[$1]' Input_file Input_file2
```

Answer (score 1):

A very ad-hoc solution to your problem could be to compose the output in a command group:

```
{ head -1 file2; awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$1 in a {print $0}' file file2; } > result
```

Comment: It's not hard to learn enough Awk to refactor the Awk script to handle everything `head` does as well.